# Project Euler #11 in C/C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have this code which is meant to solve the 11th problem from Project Euler, and it doesn't work further than `printout()`, after which it crashes with "stack overflow".
I guess that something is wrong with my indices (probably in the `next_elem` function), but I don't see what. Please, give a hint.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


const int matrix[20][20]  = {
                             {8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8},
                             {49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 4, 56, 62, 0},
                             {81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 3, 49, 13, 36, 65},
                             {52, 70, 95, 23, 4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 1, 32, 56, 71, 37, 2, 36, 91},
                             {22, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80},
                             {24, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3, 45, 2, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50},
                             {32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70},
                             {67, 26, 20, 68, 2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8, 40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21},
                             {24, 55, 58, 5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72},
                             {21, 36, 23, 9, 75, 0, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 0, 61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95},
                             {78, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 3, 80, 4, 62, 16, 14, 9, 53, 56, 92},
                             {16, 39, 5, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 0, 17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57},
                             {86, 56, 0, 48, 35, 71, 89, 7, 5, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58},
                             {19, 80, 81, 68, 5, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 4, 89, 55, 40},
                             {4, 52, 8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 7, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66},
                             {88, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 3, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69},
                             {4, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8, 46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36},
                             {20, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 4, 36, 16},
                             {20, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 1, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 5, 54},
                             {1, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 1, 89, 19, 67, 48},
                            };

unsigned long int rows[20][20], columns [20][20], diagslash[20][20], diagbackslash[20][20]; //create all necessary arrays of maximum possible dimensions

//a debugging function  -- to check that everything is right and that I'm working with indices correctly
void printout()
    {
    for(int i=0;i<20;++i)
    {
            {
                    for(int j=0;j<20;++j) 
                        std::cout << "a["<<i<<"],["<<j<<"] = " << matrix[i][j] << " " << "\n";
            }
        std::cout << "\n"; 
        }    
    }


// a function that calculates the next element from the previous one and some matrix elements
unsigned long int next_elem(int i,int j, unsigned long int array[][20])
    {
        if (matrix[i][j] == 0) // a zero in a sequence means we need to move 4 elements to the right
        {
            j+=4;
            next_elem(i,j,rows);
        }
        else if(matrix[i][j] > matrix[i][j-4])  // this condition is meant to put an increasing sequence of results into the 'rows' array
        {
            rows[i][j-4]=rows[i][j-5]*matrix[i][j-1]/matrix[i][j-1];
            next_elem(i,j,rows);
        }
        return 0;
    }



void check(int i, int j, unsigned long int array[][20]) 
    {
        if ((matrix[i][j] == 0) || (matrix[i][j+1] == 0) || (matrix[i][j+2] == 0) || (matrix[i][j+3] == 0)) //look for a zero
        {
            j+=4;
            check(i,j,rows);    
        }
        else  //no zero found, calculate the next element
        {
            rows[i][j] = matrix[i][j]*matrix[i][j+1]*matrix[i][j+2]*matrix[i][j+3]; 
            next_elem(i,j+4,rows); 
        }


    }

void sort()  //this function is meant to find maximums in 'rows', 'columns' and so on
{
    for (int i = 0; i<20;++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < 17;++j)
        {
            check(i,j,rows);
            std::cout << "rows["<<i<<"]["<<j << "] = " << rows[i][j] << std::endl; //a debugging line -- to see what's going on
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    printout();
    sort();
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. For those in doubt, *this* version is mostly in C. I'll re-write it in C++ once I get the hang of the algorithm.

Comment: Always post full error messages.

Comment: In MS VS 2012, the local debugger says: `0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00252FE4).` g++ just `segmentation faults` on me.

Comment: Can you clarify: you say your program crashes when `printout` is called, but that you suspect the culprit might be the `next_elem` function - however you don't call `next_elem` inside `printout`, and `printout` is the first thing you call inside `main`

Comment: oh, my. Sorry, have to correct that.

Comment: You are calling a function `check()` recursively so stack overflow is always a risk here if its not implemented properly. Use a debugger

Comment: Clarification: the programs works as far as `printout`, that is, `printout` does indeed print out the whole `matrix` arrays correctly - and then the program crashes with a `stack overflow`. Also, the next error the debugger reports after the `stack overflow is` an `access rights violation when trying to write to 0x00250F84.` Which makes me suspect that it tries to write where it shouldn't, which probably means something's wrong with the indices.

Comment: Can you remove any reference to the website you mention? That's not the purpose of the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is done to i or j or matrix in this situation:

```
else if(matrix[i][j] > matrix[i][j-4])  // this condition is meant to put an increasing sequence of results into the 'rows' array
{
    rows[i][j-4]=rows[i][j-5]*matrix[i][j-1]/matrix[i][j-1];
    next_elem(i,j,rows);
}
```

So it'll recurse forever, always with the same parameters, always passing through the same branch, eventually giving you a stack overflow; this would be my guess what's happening.

You need to step `i` or `j` along, or change either `matrix[i][j]` or `matrix[i][j-4]` so the condition will eventually be false, terminating the recursion.

Haven't analyzed the code or the problem further, so I don't know what you need to change :)

Comment: Now I' confused: I thought that outer loops were meant to change `i` and `j`.

Comment: @Chiffa; What outer loops? It's a recursion, you're calling `next_elem` again from within itself with the same parameters, no loop involved

Comment: With tail recursion like this, it's very easy to overflow the stack, and that happens fast. Check your recursive condition. Determine the termination condition first and allow the recursion logic to slid toward that condition. Plan first before implementing, especially recursive logic.

Comment: Function `sort` has an `i` loop, and it it a `j` loop, and then in the loop  it calls `check` and passes `i` and `j` to it. Because of the loop, `i` and `j` should change. I thought that would lead to changes in `next_elem`.

Comment: @Chiffa; If you're referring to the loops in `sort`, no offense, but I believe you're in a bit over your head, and you need to take a step back and learn about how parameters are passed, and what recursion is.

Comment: @Chiffa; even if the loops in `sort` would change the values in `next_elem` (which they do *not*, only the fact that they call `next_elem` with the new values propagates the loop values into `next_elem`), you're not giving the loop a chance to step, you're calling `next_elem` from itself, it never returns to let the loop run.

Comment: Oh, well, I thought I knew. Guess I have to check that knowledge :-)

Comment: @roe, I see. Should I change `j` in `next_elem`, then?

Comment: @Chiffa; I honestly don't know how the algorithm should work, but you need to pass new values to `next_elem`, you can't give it the same ones. Changing `j` within next_elem will have that effect, but it seems you think the variable `j` is somehow connected to all variables called `j`, and this is where we have a huge gap to cover. You probably do *not* want to change the value of `j`, but if `j` is the one that needs to change, then call `next_elem` with a new `j` value like something like this `next_elem(i,j+1,rows)`, but blindly changing stuff is unlikely to get you anywhere, sorry mate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43545/discussion-between-chiffa-and-roe)

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to track all conditions but it is pretty clear that you can easily get out of bound:

```
void check(int i, int j, unsigned long int array[][20]) 
{
    if ((matrix[i][j] == 0) || (matrix[i][j+1] == 0) || (matrix[i][j+2] == 0) || (matrix[i][j+3] == 0)) //look for a zero
    {
        j+=4; // what if j was 16 here?
        check(i,j,rows); 
    }
}
```

So as the first step I would recommend to put assert to check that all parameters in range:

```
void check(int i, int j, unsigned long int array[][20]) 
{
    assert( i >= 0 && i < 20 && j >= 0 && j < 20 );
    ...
}
```

Do same for `next_element` compile with debug enabled and check.

Answer (score 0):

You are seg faulting because:

```
for (int j = 0;j < 17;++j)
```

needs to be

```
for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j)
```

Comment: Why? That is, I tried that, and it didn't work and I wonder how you cam to think of this.

Comment: j goes from 0 to 16, and there's a possibility of adding 4 to j, so j will go from 0 to 20.  This is out of the index bounds which are 0 to 19.

Comment: While obviously wrong, it would not, in this case, cause a seg fault, as the last row contains no zeros, which is the condition for increasing by 4, thus it would quite possibly read or write beyond the end of the row into the next one, but not beyond the end of any of the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
// m is matrix
int max=0;
void update(int i){
    if(i>max)max=i;}
void main(){
    for(int i=0;i<17;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<17;j++){
            update(m[i][j]*m[i+1][j]*m[i+2][j]*m[i+3][j]);
            update(m[i][j]*m[i][j+2]*m[i][j+3]*m[i][j+4]);
            update(m[i][j]*m[i+1][j+1]*m[i+2][j+2]*m[i+3][j+3]);
            update(m[i][j+3]*m[i+1][j+2]*m[i+2][j+1]*m[i+3][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",max);
}
```